# How do I allow below URLs to my apache proxy?

Tags: apache, alfresco

Experts,

I want to allow below URLs to my apache httpd configuration httpd.conf or ssl.conf  to allow below URLs

```
**/alfresco/service/saml/-default-/aos/authenticate
/alfresco/service/saml/-default-/aos/authenticate-response
/alfresco/service/saml/-default-/rest-api/authenticate
/alfresco/service/saml/-default-/rest-api/authenticate-response**
```

As of now I allow like below on proxypass and proxypassreverse like below

```
ProxyPass /alfresco  http://alfrescodnsurl.com:8080/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco  http://alfrescodnsurl.com:8080/alfresco

ProxyPass /share http://alfrescodnsurl.com:8080/share
ProxyPassReverse /share  http://alfrescodnsurl.com:8080/share
```

I know for small context like /share or /alfresco it is fine, but to allow above long URLs how do I proceed with my apache configuration?

Also my final url is alfrescodnsurl which does not having port (I mean port will not appear out side world) how do I proceed in this case.

Comment: Do you want those saml URLs to be proxied to Alfresco? Or do you want to terminate them on httpd itself without going to Alfresco?

Comment: I want those URLs to allow instead block to alfresco

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding you. What exactly do you want to happen or not happen?

Comment: How do I allow above URLs to proxy my apache webserver. (Allow) not deny.